# Sum duplicate row values from two tables

Tags: sql, group-by, sum

I'm trying to get the following information from two tables in one row, but when i use group by i always get two rows:

Doc Headers

```
Section Doc     Year    Nr
SEC1    PATAG   2017    7386
```

Doc Lines

```
Section Doc     Year    Nr      Line Type   Quantity
SEC1    PATAG   2017    7386    0           1.000000
SEC1    PATAG   2017    7386    4           2.000000
```

Query

```
SELECT
cab.strCodSeccao as [Section], cab.strAbrevTpDoc as [Doc], cab.strCodExercicio 
as [Year], cab.intNumero as [Nr], 
Cast (SUM (lin.fltQuantidade) as NUMERIC (15,2) ) as [Quantity],
CASE WHEN lin.intTpEntPagador = 0 THEN Cast (SUM (lin.fltQuantidade) as 
NUMERIC (15,2) ) ELSE 0 END as [Qtd Client],
CASE WHEN lin.intTpEntPagador = 4 THEN Cast (SUM (lin.fltQuantidade) as 
NUMERIC (15,2) ) ELSE 0 END as [Qtd Warranty]

FROM    
Mov_Apv_Reparacao_Lin as lin WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Mov_Apv_Reparacao_Cab as cab ON 
(lin.strCodseccao=cab.strCodSeccao AND Cab.strAbrevTpDoc=Lin.strAbrevTpDoc AND 
Cab.strCodExercicio=Lin.strCodExercicio AND Cab.intNumero=Lin.intNumero)

WHERE   
cab.strAbrevTpDoc='PATAG' AND cab.strcodexercicio = 
2017 and cab.intnumero = 7386

GROUP BY 
cab.strCodSeccao, cab.strAbrevTpDoc, cab.strCodExercicio, cab.intNumero, 
lin.intTpEntPagador
```

Result from Query

```
Section Doc     Year    Nr      Quantity    Qtd Client  Qtd Warranty
SEC1    PATAG   2017    7386    1.00        1.00        0.00
SEC1    PATAG   2017    7386    2.00        0.00        2.00
```

Desired result

```
Section Doc     Year    Nr      Quantity    Qtd Client  Qtd Warranty
SEC1    PATAG   2017    7386    3.00        1.00        2.00
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an attribute too much in your `group by`: you should remove `lin.intTpEntPagador`. That also means you have to change your case/summations:

```
Cast(SUM(CASE WHEN lin.intTpEntPagador = 0 THEN lin.fltQuantidade ELSE 0 END) as 
NUMERIC (15,2) ) as [Qtd Client]
```

You should also remove the `distinct`, it has no function if you also `group by`

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your `SUM()` outside of your `CASE`:

```
SELECT cab.strCodSeccao as [Section], 
       cab.strAbrevTpDoc as [Doc], 
       cab.strCodExercicio as [Year], 
       cab.intNumero as [Nr], 
       CAST(SUM(lin.fltQuantidade) as NUMERIC (15,2)) as [Quantity],
       CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN lin.intTpEntPagador = 0 
            THEN lin.fltQuantidade
            ELSE 0 
       END) AS NUMERIC (15,2)) as [Qtd Client],
       CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN lin.intTpEntPagador = 4 
            THEN lin.fltQuantidade
            ELSE 0 
       END) AS NUMERIC (15,2)) as [Qtd Warranty]
```

Side note, no need for `DISTINCT` here when you already have a `GROUP BY`